# Convert DataGrid cell content

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, datatable, converters

I have a DataGrid whose ItemsSource is set to a DataTable. The DataTable has a column of type DateTime, and I would like to display informational text (ie. "N/A") if the date in a particular cell is a certain value.

My first thought was to somehow bind the cell content to itself, and use a converter, but I can't seem to get it working correctly, and it seems as though there should be a better way.

Additionally, both the DataGrid and DataTable are dynamically generated, so this has to be done in the code behind.

Here's the code I tried initially:

```
// Create a new DataGridCellStyle
Style myStyle = new Style();
myStyle.TargetType = typeof(DataGridCell);

// Create the binding
Binding myBinding = new Binding();
myBinding.RelativeSource = RelativeSource.Self;
myBinding.Converter = new DateTimeToStringConverter();

// Add the Content setter
Setter mySetter = new Setter();
mySetter.Property = ContentProperty;  
mySetter.Value = myBinding;
myStyle.Setters.Add(setter);

// Set the Style and ItemsSource
myDataGrid.CellStyle = myStyle ;
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = myDataTable.DefaultView;
```

DateTimeToStringConverter does implement IValueConverter, but I'm guessing the problem lies somewhere with the binding, since DateTimeToStringConverter is never actually called when the DataGrid is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

At first, you Add the variable with the name **setter** to the Setters collection, but you are define the variable with the name **mySetter**. It may be a reason, why your Converter is not actually called.

Also the solution for your problem will be a bit more complicated.
Actually the Convert get a value of type RowDataView which contains a data for whole row. There is not an information in the converter about a Column or a Cell that is actually binded.

Better will be skip AutoGenerateColumns and generate them programmatically.
Here is example:

```
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = myDataTable.DefaultView;
myDataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

foreach (DataColumn column in myDataTable.Columns)
{
    Binding binding = new Binding(column.ColumnName)
        {
            Converter = new DateTimeToStringConverter()
        };
    DataGridColumn gridColumn = new DataGridTextColumn 
        { 
            SortMemberPath = column.ColumnName, 
            Header = column.ColumnName, 
            Binding = binding 
        };
    myDataGrid.Columns.Add(gridColumn);
}
```

Of course, for a performance will be better use the converter only in a DateTime columns.